# Calling a Stored Procedure in MongoDB via C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a saved function in system.js called "addNumbers" which has 2 parameters:

```
function addNumbers( a , b ) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I wish to execute this function via C#, by adding 2 numbers which are inputted by a user.  So far I have the following code:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("test");

Console.WriteLine("Input two numbers: ");
string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
BsonValue bv = test.Eval("addNumbers", num1, num2);
BsonValue bv1 = test.Eval(bv.AsBsonJavaScript.Code, num1, num2);
```

What I am doing wrong? As no sum is being displayed

Comment: how did you load the system.js?

Comment: since the system.js is situated in the 'test' database, I thought that you do not need to load it (since I specified where it is)

Comment: I see. I thought you were storing it in another JS file. Usually it's not recommended to execute server side JS as per suggested by [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/#store-a-javascript-function-on-the-server). You code works for me though. You didn't write it in console. that's why it's not displayed.

Comment: You're right thanks! I added Console.Write(bv1); at the end.  But, when I inputted the numbers 2 and 3 to be added, '23' was displayed.  Looks like it just displayed the 2 inputted numbers.  Do you know why this happened please?

Comment: see my answer. you need to parse string to int first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just did a test locally. With

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id : "myAddFunction" ,
    value : function (x, y){ return x + y; }
});
```

I got a saved function myAddFunction. With a little bit modification of your code:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.122.1/test");
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("test");

Console.WriteLine("Input two numbers: ");
string num1Str = Console.ReadLine();
string num2Str = Console.ReadLine();
int num1 = int.Parse(num1Str);
int num2 = int.Parse(num2Str);

BsonValue bv = test.Eval("myAddFunction");
BsonValue bv1 = test.Eval(bv.AsBsonJavaScript.Code, num1, num2);
Console.WriteLine(bv1);
```

Now I get the right result displayed.

Comment: Do remember not to use it in production. It slows your app down a lot.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I continued working on this.  To receive a user input which is in the form of a MongoDB command, you have to declare it as BsonValue?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: did you try input a string angry pass it to vain value? I believe BsonValue has a method Parse or something.

Comment: Seems the auto-correct of my phone doesn't work very well. Glad you figured it out anyway :)

Comment: @yaoxing Could you please tell me why invoking javaScript using C# MongoDB driver API in a C# application will slow performance?  Also, how could I improve it if do need to put some javaScript when it comes to retrieving data from the MongoDB database?

Comment: @CSLewis it's not specific to C#, I'm actually talking about running JS in MongoDB is not a good idea. Prior to 2.4, JS [holds a global write lock](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/#concurrency) which blocks all the other read/write operations. Changed from 2.4 you can change the default behavior to not to hold any lock by specifying {nolock: true} option. It's still not recommended as the [eval](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) method is deprecated from 3.0.

Comment: That is kind of a roadblock for me.   I use MongoDB 3.0.0 and MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714.  I was hoping javascript method would be pseudo-store procedures in my C# web application.  Using the C# MongodB API that brings in Objects into the C# world really slow performance.  Could you please provide me an alternative?

Comment: @CSLewis It's hard to suggest without knowing what you want to do exactly. besides, to discuss a problem that is not related to the current one, it's better to open another question so that you can draw people's attention, not only from me.

Comment: this code in not working with driver 2.4.0 . eval function was removed.

Comment: @FDB As I said above, it's not a good idea to call JS in MongoDB due to bad performance. And now it's officially removed. Actually everything that can be done with JS can also be done with drivers. If you have a scenario in which only JS applies, please open a new question and discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your stored function and get returned result follow this way:

```
var num1 = Console.ReadLine();
var num2 = Console.ReadLine();
var command = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>($"{{ eval: \"addNumbers({num1},{num2})\" }}");
var result = db.RunCommand(command)["retval"].ToInt32();
```