# Run javascript file from MongoDB C# driver

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use [Variety](https://github.com/variety/variety), a custom tool/script for MongoDB (2.6) in the C# driver for MongoDB.

I was able to run it successfully through the commandline, but I'm unsure how to run it's equivalent in the C# driver.

> bin\mongo db --eval "var collection = 'coll', limit = 20" bin\variety.js

## 1. Javascript location

I ran the command above when the javascript was located in `bin\` next to `mongo.exe`. Following [the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) I went on and placed the file in `\data\db\scripts`. However I also read about the `system.js` file.

**Is placing it in `\data\db\scripts` the right way? Or do I have to *register* it in `system.js`?**

## 2. Running the script

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709351/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-mongodb-via-c-sharp) on running a stored procedure in MongoDB shows how to execute a method with two arguments. However the Variety tool uses some sort of context variables which I need to provide in order for it to execute (`collection` and `limit` for instance). In the commandline they are provided as string which is evaluated before the name of the script file.

**What is the equivalent of the commandline execution? I can't get the `result2` variable right. How do I pass an entire script file instead of a function name?**

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://0.0.0.0/db");
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("db");

BsonValue result1 = db.Eval("var collection = 'coll', limit = 20");
BsonValue result2 = db.Eval(result1.AsBsonJavaScript.Code, "variety.js");
```

Comment: Read the documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Comment: Did you read the link?  You "save" JavaScript functions to the server. Then in your calls to the server with JavaScript code, you reference those functions to execute. Not what I would recommend though. If you think you need JavaScript execution then your document structure really should be changed,

Comment: Yes, the link to the documentation was already in my question? Your comment makes no sense to me. Are you saying I shouldn't use Variety or ServerSide Javascript?

Comment: Good. I thought I would let it sink in before responding. The points are 1. use the server side saved functions or submit in one go where you need to. And 2. If you need to "traverse" structures with JavaScript code because there is no other option then you "should" re-evaluate, as there are likely better ways to structure the documents you want to use. The big "offender" here is using what should be "data" as names of "keys". Think about that. But that information is not in this question. Maybe ask another one.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: 1. I get I can submit serverside `functions`, i don't get how this relates to the javascript `file` I have. Or maybe I should `load()` the file in the function that I define?(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/). 2. If you mean "evaluate: `var collection = 'coll', limit = 20`" by "traversing Javascript structures" I think I see where you're going... I know the part contains some hardcoded pieces, but that's not the point of my question so I can hardly think this is what you mean?