# Call MongoDB Stored Javascript Function in C# .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to call a MongoDB Stored JavaScript Function in C# Code.

My Stored JavaScript Function **GetUserInfo**

```
function() {
    return db.getCollection('Profession').find({});
}
```

Execution :

```
db.loadServerScripts();

GetUserInfo();
```

It returns the Collection with following documents (Here I pasted only 2 Documents, in real I'm having more than 10K Documents)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575845a713d284da0ac2ee81"),
    "Profession_id" : "575841b313d284da0ac2ee7d",
    "Prof_Name" : "Chief Officer"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575845d213d284da0ac2ee82"),
    "Profession_id" : "575841b313d284da0ac2ee7d",
    "Prof_Name" : "Executive Officer"
}
```

In C#:

```
IMongoClient _client;
IMongoDatabase _database;

_client = new MongoClient();
_database = _client.GetDatabase("SampleDB");
```

Kindly assist me how to call MongoDB Stored JavaScript Function in C# Code.

The following Question uses **`Eval`**. In the latest driver, **I can't able to find the Extended Function `_database.Eval`**

[Calling a Stored Procedure in MongoDB via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709351/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-mongodb-via-c-sharp)

Kindly assist me...

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709351/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-mongodb-via-c-sharp

Comment: It's not working for the current C# driver. There is no extended function Eval. I assist me...

Comment: http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_Eval_1.htm isn't that the eval function, that can be used?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jamesikanos/b5897b1693b5c3dd1f87 that can help

Comment: @ntohl -  Dead Link. Kindly check the link. 404 Error - Hmm, we can't reach this page.

Comment: @ntohl - Right now we are using C# Driver 2.2.4

Comment: Why do you want to use JS evaluation?

Comment: @user3100115 I wish to write the important logics and costly operations in MongoDB JavaScript functions instead of C#. So, how to call and fetch the values from the Mongo Functions. Kindly assist me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RunCommand method](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase_RunCommand__1.htm) to execute the eval command. We've removed it from the API itself because we don't want you using it. Have a look at these sections for why you shouldn't be using eval, [first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) and [second](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/).

I'd highly suggest you rethink your "stored procedure" strategy. While I applaud your efforts to centralize and DRY your code, eval in MongoDB will kill performance and concurrency.

Comment: can you give a sample for use  RunCommand to call a stored javascript?